# How to think this algorithm problem about query find in an array?

Tags: algorithm

There's a hidden array `arr`, given its length `n` and a set of queries `[L, R]`. **The query [L, R] means that we have already known the sum between arr[L] and arr[R] both inclusively, e.g. arr[L]+arr[L+1]+...+arr[R-1]+arr[R]**, return **all possible indexes** that we can get the corresponding value of `arr`. Here's an example:

If we set n = 3, queries = [[1,3], [2,2], [3,3]], then the answer should be [1,2,3]. Because from the queries, we have known the sum of `arr[1]+arr[2]+arr[3]`, [2,2] and [3,3] means we also have known the value of arr[2] and arr[3], so we can finally get the value of arr[1].

Both the n and the number of queries satisfies: 1 <= n, the length of queries <= 10^5.

I had been thinking about `union find` to solve this problem at first sight, but I can't set up their connections. It would be appreciated if someone gives me the hint, thanks!

Comment: What does the queries mean? What does a given query of `[L,R]` do? Please elaborate.

Comment: The query [L, R] means that we have already known the sum between arr[L] and arr[R] both inclusively, e.g. arr[L]+arr[L+1]+...+arr[R-1]+arr[R], have edited! Thanks for your attention. @cSharp

Comment: As a hint: this can be naturally viewed as a linear algebra problem. Treat each query [L, R] as an n-dimensional column vector, with ones in indices L through R and zeros elsewhere. Then, you're looking for the space spanned by those column vectors, which you can find with [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Comment: So this is not the algorithm problem but the mathematics question?  @kcsquared

Comment: It's both; Gaussian elimination is a mathematical algorithm. It doesn't seem obviously solvable using union-find, though.

Comment: I guess a naïve answer would be to look at each element (n times), and loop through the queries and dynamically store the smallest query sum you know as you go. This would probably have the time complexity of `n * q (no. of queries)` but that should be a good starting point.